# Add sound through onclick-event button

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to add sound to these buttons

```
<a href="stout_page.html"><audio id="sound1" src="Button_Push.mp3" preload="auto"></audio><button onClick="document.getElementId('sound1').play();" target="_top">Stouts</button></a>
<a href="sours_page.html"><button target="_top">Sours</button></a>
<a href="ipa_page.html"><button target="_top">India Pale Ales</button>.      </a>
<a href="brett and more.html"><button target="_top">Brett and more</button></a>
<a href="test_page.html"><button target="_top">test</button></a>
```

Comment: Try to include a definite question in the body of your question.  It may also help to describe what is actually happening (e.g. precisely what happens when you load the page with your problematic HTML), what you've tried do in order to arrive at the desired behaviour, and what exactly that desired behaviour is.  e.g. Would you like a sound to play if the button is clicked, hovered?

Answer (score 0):

you can add sounds to button but it will refresh page as you are using `href` on click of `a` tag. inside that `button` click will call **play** function to play the sound.

```
<script>
  function play(src) {
    var player = document.getElementById('audio');
    player.pause();
    player.currentTime = 0;
    player.src = src;
    player.play();
  }
</script>

<input type="button" value="PLAY" onclick="play('http://dev.interactive-creation-works.net/1/1.ogg')">
<audio id="audio" src="http://dev.interactive-creation-works.net/1/1.ogg" autostart="false"></audio>

<a href="stout_page.html"><audio id="sound1" src="Button_Push.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<button onClick="play('Button_Push.mp3');" target="_top">Stouts</button></a>
<a href="sours_page.html"><button target="_top" onClick="play('Button_Push-1.mp3');" >Sours</button></a>
<a href="ipa_page.html"><button target="_top" onClick="play('Button_Push-2.mp3');">India Pale Ales</button></a>
<a href="brett and more.html"><button target="_top" onClick="play('Button_Push-3.mp3');">Brett and more</button></a>
<a href="test_page.html"><button target="_top" onClick="play('Button_Push-4.mp3');">test</button></a>
```

Comment: the <input type="button"> worked but the href with the a tag did not. Any other suggestions?

Comment: what you want to achieve here exactly? play sound then move to page ?

Comment: yes its playing sound when returning to previous page